# How to make a MS Ofiice type File menu in top left corner in wxribbon in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using the wx.ribbon in wxpython. I have it working well for simple buttons. Right now it looks like this.
[basic wx ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8nk6.png)

Now I want to add a "File" menu in the top left as is done in office. I want it to look like this.
[ribbon with file menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t2dR.png)

I am speculating that it is related to the ribbon style options but I have had no luck getting anything to show up. Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more info if you want anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Hey chrisz. Thanks for trying to help. I have edited my question